# systemd: Restart units stopped by Conflicts option

Tags: systemd

I have two services A and B which run continuously, for them I use `systemd` service units. At specific times service C should be run, I can do this using a timer and a service with the same name. C finishes after a short time. When C runs, A and B should not run. To ensure this, I use in the service file for C the `Conflicts=` option, which is explained on this webpage: [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html). But this options only stops A and B. How can I start A and B again, when C finishes? Can I do this using `systemd`?

Note: To call `systemctl start A.service` and `systemctl start B.service` is not the kind of solution I am looking for.

Comment: I guess it's a dirty way to do that... can you trigger `A` and `B` in `ExecStop` of `C`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using:

[ExecStopPost](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStopPost=)`=/usr/bin/systemctl start A.service B.service`

> Additional commands that are executed after the service is stopped

Using `ExecStopPost` instead of `ExecStop` is important because when `ExecStop` is run the service is still considered up, so the conflict will still apply.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will use your first suggestion. I think there is a misunderstanding, I have no objections to your first suggestion.

Comment: my complaint with this solution is that it requires editing the C unit file.  I would like to see a solution that only requires editing the A and/or B unit files.

Comment: @gam3 I would disagree - `C.service` is the one with special requirements, so it should be responsible for making its requirements true. Editing A and B is more impact (editing two services instead of one) so that they can do the work that C requires for it.